# FeathersJS and VueJS 2 coexistence (repo)

Tags: vue.js, feathersjs

I want a simple way to have scaffolded versions of feathers and vue, where they both use their -cli utilities, but in such way they don't mess with each other, but can be deployed at once. Requisites:

1. I don't feathers-js to recompile things because something changed
   in the vue sub-folder.
2. I want to deploy everything to heroku and
   build as it is just one thing (that is, only one "package.json",
   only one "npm start".
3. I want to use express capabilities of
   feathers to not only provide the rest/sockets services but also,
   serve the html/vue-bundled-js.

I've seen several examples where you just create one "server" and one "client" folder, which is great for separation between client-server, but then... how do you include the vue app bundle into the feathers served static (public) and to make all happen seamlessly.

Also please let me know if I'm wrong with any of my "requirements" (a.k.a.: I should change my mindset).

Comment: Vue.js and feathers do completely different things.  Just use each one normally; you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Sure, but I want to deploy them together as just one web app (server and client) let's say, in heroku.

Comment: So deploy the files, including the Webpack output.  What's the problem?

Comment: I'll have to execute then both vue's npm build and then the feather's npm build/start, right?

Comment: Yes; you'll need to run two build scripts.

Comment: ok. Fair enough. I'm used to have a sails+angular architecture were I only need to run the sails grunt. I hate that architecture now, but that part was quite convenient.

Comment: You can edit package.json to run both scripts together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any static file serving middleware to serve your compiled Vue bundles (from webpack) in your Express app.

Comment: so I'd have to modify vue webpack build config to copy the bundle to the statically served folder of my feathersjs? which "npm start" script should lead? remember I'm also interested on the continuous deployment of this two pieces of the product.